# Why are there so many attacks on a specific server?

Tags: nginx, web-server, hacking

I have a couple of web-servers running, and one of them have received 6000 attemps to gain access in the past 6 months. 
The other practically none.

Is this a coincidence, or is there something that I can do about it or something that attracts hackers?

Edit: as I'm spinning up new servers, some seem to get hackers attention right away. This may well be because of the IP address is reused from a former server that was an attractive one for hackers for some reason or another.

Comment: 6000 in six months?  I'm not sure this is really worth stressing over; my server rejected over 22,000 attempts **yesterday**, and it is by no means a big, important box.  I think my point is that if one of your servers sees 6000 attempts in six months, and the other next to none, you should congratulate yourself on having them *both* fairly off-the-radar, rather than regarding one of them as a high-profile target of some kind.

Comment: Okay, nice that my server is not as popular as your server! Good to hear that this is not uncommon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6000 attacks per month is very less, i received port knocking on ssh above 20k and on port 80 above 40k each month .

this has nothing to do with you server vulnerability . but for security purpose consider hardening your services. both of ubuntu/debian and redhat/centos flavours there are couple of good guide one can follow.

if you are servicing web app OWASP is a good start.

also for ssh i suggest to use public key based authentication instead of password.

Comment: No, I don't think my server is vulnerable, running fail2ban and use public key authentication already. Just wondering why one server receives more attacks than the other.